# Android UDP receive / waiting for incoming data

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp

I would like to send data every 5 sec over udp socket, however I always have to listen to the UDP port if any data are coming.

How can I do that?

I thought with two thread but I am not sure that would be the a best choice.

Comment: It's the simplest choice.

Comment: No other way? So I have to take the reciver and a sender part in a thread while(true)?

Comment: I didn't say there was 'no other way'. I said it's the simplest choice. What's your problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

You may do it in one single thread or AsyncTask; You want to send data every 5 seconds and you have to wait those 5 seconds for every message sent, wait one second 5 times checking, in that loop, if there is data to be read.
Also you may wait 1/2 a second 10 times in case you need to check more frequently.

Comment: Is there any event when data recieved?